# Confused about how object references work in Java

Tags: java, object-reference

I am confused about how object references work and was wondering if someone could help.  Below is some example code which is supposed to deQueue a Queue based on a linked list for the general case:

```
Object head = listHead.datum;
listHead = listHead.next;
return head;
```

My understanding is that when you have a primitive variable the actual value is stored is assigned to it, but if the variable is an object then a reference to an object is stored in there.  So in the above code a reference to listHead.datum is stored in head, but then the reference stored in listHead is changed to be listHead.next.  When it comes time to return the Object called head I would have thought that it would follow it's assigned reference i.e. go to listHead (which now refers to a different place) and then to datum.

The above code should return the head of the Queue but following my logic it will return the second in the queue.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: May I ask what variable type "listHead" is?

Comment: @cworner1 It's probably just a linked-list node of some kind.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying - yes, listHead is type Node and contains a reference to the first Node in the linked list.

Comment: Its okay, I just had an issue with passing by reference and by value. So I too would like to understand the problem and the answer for future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have:

```
Object head = listHead.datum;
listHead = listHead.next;
return head;
```

There are a number of references at play here:

- `listHead` is a reference
- `head` is a reference
- `listHead.datum` is a reference
- `listHead.next` is a reference

There are two actual object instances being referenced:

- whatever `datum` references (let's call that instance `D`)
- whatever `next` references (let's call that instance `N`)

Here's how things go down.

- `listHead.datum` has a reference to `D`
- `listHead.next` has a reference to `N`
- `head` is given a reference to `D`
- listHead is given a reference to `N`  (note that `head` is not changed)
- you return `head` which still references `D`

Comment: Ah I see!  They way I thought it worked was that the reference stored in head was like a set of directions to go to listHead and then to datum.  So when head was returned it would follow these directions.  So the "directions" are only followed to find the memory location which is stored in head.  So regardless of how parts of the "directions" are changed head still only refers to that memory location

Comment: Pretty much.  It may not be a memory location exactly, so don't get too attached to that idea.  If you're familiar with the C language, I do often think of them as being much like C pointers.  If you're not familiar with C, forget I said anything about it as it'd only confuse you. =)

Answer (score 4):

The `head` reference isn't updated dynamically as `listHead` changes. In fact, no object reference has dynamic resolution. The reference has to be explicitly changed through direct assignment. This is the only way to achieve what you thought was happening:

```
Object head = listHead.datum;
listHead = listHead.next;
// Only direct assignment can change the object that head points to
head = listHead.datum;
return head;
```